# Modifying strace to capture and replace the filename in an open syscall

Tags: c, linux, strace, ptrace

I'm trying to modify strace to capture the file open syscall and change the file that is actually opened. For example, the user tries:
open(OUT,">input.txt"), but the file that really will be opened is "input.txt.version1".

I have had some success when the length of the new name is exactly the same as the length of the old name, by using ptrace(PTRACE_POKEDATA, pid,  addr, laddr). I'm intercepting the open call in open.c and modifying umoven in util.c to poke instead of peek to replace characters.

But, this fails when the new filename is longer, because it can overrun the original filename array length. What I really need to do is replace the pointer to the char array with a new pointer to my own string.

The filename is in tcp->u_arg[0], which is the rdi register on x86 systems. I have tried variations of the following with no luck:

```
struct user_regs_struct      x86_64_r;
uint64_t *const x86_64_rdi_ptr = (uint64_t *) &x86_64_r.rdi;
ptrace(PTRACE_POKEDATA, tcp->pid,  x86_64_rdi_ptr, &newPath);
```

How can I replace the filename with a new path of arbitrary length?
An answer using only ptrace instead of a modification of strace would be fine too. strace just takes care of so many other issues already.

Comment: To the downvoter: please explain.

Comment: Why would one want to do this? Sounds like malicious software.

Comment: @Olaf It could be useful for debugging...

Comment: There are many legitimate reasons to do that. (testing and compatibility w/o modifying the original program are among them)

Comment: @Olaf this is for automatic versioning, without requiring the original program to be altered, as suggested in the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not `ptrace`, nor `strace`, but you can do that with `LD_PRELOAD` by hooking the `open` function.

*Edit: as per @JonathanLeffler comment, I tried to fix the hook function prototype, to handle the mode argument (if given) I am not 100% sure that this will always work, but it should give the idea of how to do that.*

hook.c

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h> //mode_t
#include <stdarg.h>  //va_arg

typedef int (*pfn_open_t)(const char *pathname, int flags, mode_t mode);

int open(const char *pathname, int flags, ...)
{
    pfn_open_t o_open;
    va_list val;
    mode_t mode;
    o_open = (pfn_open_t)dlsym(RTLD_NEXT,"open");
    // Extract vararg (mode)
    va_start(val, flags);
    mode = va_arg(val, mode_t);
    va_end(val);
    if(strcmp(pathname, "origfile") == 0)
    {
         puts("opening otherfile\n");
         return o_open("otherfile", flags, mode);
    }
    else
    {
         printf("opening %s\n", pathname);
         return o_open(pathname,flags, mode);
    }
}
```

compile the code as shared object:

```
gcc -shared -fPIC  hook.c -o libhook.so -ldl
```

run the program with your hook:

```
$ LD_PRELOAD=path/to/libhook.so myprogram
```

Comment: This is an interesting approach. I'll go back and work on it. I assume this could work for any system call?

Comment: Picking nits: your `pfn_open_t` type doesn't match the official prototype of `open()` which has a `...` parameter, as you clearly know.  If the flags include O_CREAT, you need to pass that third parameter.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler - Thanks for pointing that out. I ignored that issue when I posted the answer, but this is an important issue to address. I will try and fix it. If you have a solution in hand - please feel free to edit my answer, or post it separately. I will be happy to see it :)

Comment: What you've got is close to what I'd use.  Since the user might not pass a `mode_t` unless `flags` includes O_CREAT, I'd probably have: `mode_t mode = 0666; if (flags & O_CREAT) { va_list args; va_start(args, flags); mode = va_arg(args, int); va_end(args); }` to only collect it if it was (should have been) provided.  What you've got will usually work, though the mode value might be a bit eccentric on occasion — but that shouldn't formally matter.  The 'refinement' (nominal trick — but really mostly busy-work for limited or no advantage) would be to make the function calls depending on O_CREAT.

Comment: This solution works in some cases ("touch origfile") for example, but fails in other cases: perl -e "open(IN,'>origfile');".  I need this to work in all cases, or at least understand the differences, before I can accept this answer.

Comment: Turns out I need to capture open64 for perl. Is there a list so I don't miss anything else?